# use git show on a tag which has same name as file

Tags: git

I have an annotated tag that's called folicp but there is also a file with the same name so when I try to run

```
git show folicp
```

I get `fatal: ambiguous argument 'test': both revision and filename`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `git show folicp --`. The `--` distinguishes refs from filenames.

Alternatively you could use the fully-qualified tag name, `git show refs/tags/folicp`